# canvas bezier curves for parametric eq

Tags: canvas, bezier

I'm trying to use canvas to emulate a parametric equalizer that responds similar to the following image of an equalizer, using Frequency, Resonance and Gain.

[image: eq parametric]

There are 8 points along a line. Each point can have a variety of curves (low pass, bell, notch, high pass etc)

I'm wondering how I can emulate this in canvas?

There are a bunch of generators online, like this - https://canvature.appspot.com/
 but they dont really show you how to do multiple curves along a line. 
Also, for instance most of the tools I've seen cannot do high resonance - do I need to use an extra point for these?

I can use the canvas bezierCurveTo and moveTo functions, and I will input XY movements for each point into these.

Any pointers on how to calculate these responses would be amazing

Cheers

K

EDIT

I believe the user beneath is correct, I need B-splines to achieve this in canvas. So far I have tried a simple low pass curve that moves from right to left (without any resonance). I'm struggling to add resonance , which properly emulates the resonance of a low pass curve (ie with a peak at the beginning, not across the whole path). e.g. http://www.audiomulch.com/images/blog/southpole-expedition-part-1-low-pass-filter-basics-resonant-low-pass-frequency-response.png

I'm also struggling that I need to have 8 points along the line and one point can pass through another point (thereby affecting the B-spline). I'm guessing I need to use the `isPointInPath()` function for this, but struggling on how to implement it in my use case.

I'm guessing this is so hard because it hasnt been attempted before in Canvas, and theres very little info around the web regarding this (I can find plenty of examples in C)

Here is an example of the low pass curve I've made with a little resonance using a B-spline (but the resonance doesnt go far enough, the peak should be more reduced)

Sorry about the strange coding style, this is not javascript, but a basic scripting language that has integrated all the canvas functions:

```
canvas_beginPath(c);
decl x0 = x[0] * 1000;
decl y0 = y[0] * 200;
decl x1 = x[1] * 200;
decl y1 = y[1] * 20;

canvas_lineTo(c,0, 10); 
canvas_moveTo(c,x0+10, 98);             
canvas_arcTo(c,x0+103, 200-y0, x0+173, 96, 73); 
canvas_lineTo(c,1000, 96);             
canvas_stroke(c);
canvas_fill(0);

canvas_beginPath(d);
canvas_moveTo(d,165, 98);            
canvas_arcTo(d,203, 95, 281, 96, 73); 
canvas_lineTo(d,1000, 96);             
canvas_stroke(d);
canvas_fill(0);
```

Comment: This doesn't have nearly enough detail to explain what you *actually* want. Pretend there is no audio application, because you're sidetracking your own question by pretending the canvas has anything to do with emulating anything: it's just a drawing surface, what are you concretely trying to draw on the canvas here?

Comment: For a high Q/resonance you would need to add a couple of extra points in there. But to answer this question as-is we would actually have to solve the whole thing for you. What did you try so far? If any code, please share. Also check B-splines (not to be confused with Bezier) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-spline

Comment: Hi Ken, good points. I've updated my post with some more information. Good call on the B-spline.

Comment: Hi Mike, the various filters have very specific responses. I have to emulate them by drawing them on a canvas. e.g. http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/filter/filter_7.html

Comment: @Ke, that bleeds two unrelated things into each other: drawing on the canvas does not in any way impact how you code applies the filter curve to your audio - so for the canvas, what you want is to just draw certain curves, which means it's a very simple problem of "how do I draw filter curve X between two points". That part is pretty simple, and nearly all the filters you list can be done as a cubic Bezier between each pair of equalizer points.

Comment: Hi Mike, the bit im struggling with on canvas, is how to make all these points appear along the same line/path (I can make them all have different lines, but then they cannot interact with each other, when one point passes through the other) and then Im strugging how to emulate those curves in canvas (I can draw a basic curve, but I cant get the resonance steep enough).

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with "interact with each other"? The problem with your question is that you're not being specific, asking "how I can emulate a variety of curves", which doesn't mean anything. The hard part comes, entirely, from a lack of details (I can program up a storm of curves in canvas in minutes, that part is absolutely not a challenge for anyone familiar with the Canvas2d API)

Answer (score 3):

I havent understood it that much but from what I did in another circumstance (I had fix points and need to provide a human like recognition curve).

Here is what I got from your problem:

You have certain amplitudes along a spectrum of frequencies. Since the frequencies are an ordered set (inherits a natural order from the number space), you actually have a sample set and need to interpolate between those to form a function.

This interpolation can be done with lines:

```
*               ******    *
  *          ***       **   *
    *    ***                  *
      **                        *
```

So in the end this does not look good.

There is another way horizontal lines

```
****     *********             
                   ******          
                                   
     *****               ******
```

This is used by digital amplifiers to visualize it.

What you seek is something more round:

```
**          ****  ****
  **      **    **    **
    *   **              *
     ***                 *
```

Ok to do so you just use a bspline with four points

```
+        ***x
       **
      *
    **
x***        +
```

The both x points are the first and fourth point the point this spline goes through. These two points are your points to represent the values.

The + points are point 2 and three that actually control the roundness of point one (point 2 does this) and four point four (point three) does that. If you place those points on the same y-achse values you can control the roundness with the x access.

If point 2 has the same x as point four (remember 2 controls the roundness for one) then the spline goes through the middle point as long as 3 has the same x value as point one. This middle point can be moved by altering the x values of 2 and three easily. Play with it.

I had very pleasant results with using 100% and 100% but in the end let the people adjust those for the curve. (I use values between 0 and 1).

You can see the effect yourself by using illustrator or freehand and use the bspline tool (path edit) and use the roundness points (those you drag out and move at each point of the path) and alter only the x values.

This is exactly what you are looking for.

If you need help or need a real picture (I know the ascii art is not good enough), just ask I will update the post.

Answer (score 3):

A parametric equalizer filters a signal. What you're trying to visualize with a curve is the frequency response of the filter.

A simple way to do this is to compute the response at many different frequencies (e.g., once at each pixel column in the visualization) to get a bunch of points in the visualization. Then, just draw line segments through consecutive points to visualize the frequency response of the filter.

The point is, use the actual frequency response function to interpolate points along the curve for rendering, rather than canvas's built in support for Bezier curves.